# Struct property as key and the struct itself as value in HashMaps

Tags: rust, struct

The following is a snippet of a more complicated code, the idea is loading a SQL table and setting a hashmap with one of the table struct fields as the key and keeping the structure as the value (implementation details are not important since the code works fine if I clone the `String`, however, the Strings in the DB can be arbitrarily long and cloning can be expensive).

The following code will fail with

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `foo`
  --> src/main.rs:24:35
   |
24 |         foo_hashmap.insert(foo.a, foo);
   |                            -----  ^^^ value used here after partial move
   |                            |
   |                            value partially moved here
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `foo.a` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`.
```

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

fn main() {
    let foo_1 = Foo {
        a: "bar".to_string(),
        b: "bar".to_string(),
    };

    let foo_2 = Foo {
        a: "bar".to_string(),
        b: "bar".to_string(),
    };

    let foo_vec = vec![foo_1, foo_2];

    let mut foo_hashmap = HashMap::new();

    foo_vec.into_iter().for_each(|foo| {
        foo_hashmap.insert(foo.a, foo);  // foo.a.clone() will make this compile
    });
}
```

The struct `Foo` cannot implement `Copy` since its fields are String. I tried wrapping `foo.a` with `Rc::new(RefCell::new())` but later went down the pitfall of missing the trait Hash for `RefCell<String>`, so currently I'm not certain in either using something else for the struct fields (will `Cow` work?), or to handle that logic within the `for_each` loop.

Comment: I've hit this exact issue before. It's a bit of a mess. Personally, I just take the hit and `clone` the key, to cut out that dependency altogether. Minor performance hit but you can be confident your code is correct.

Comment: This can't work, because as soon as you have an immutable borrow against a value in the hashmap, you can never mutably borrow the hashmap again -- otherwise you could cause a reallocation that invalidates the reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two problems here: First, the resulting `HashMap<K, V>` would be a self-referential struct, as the `K` borrows `V`; there are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) questions and answers on SA about the pitfalls of this. Second, even if you could construct such a `HashMap`, you'd easily break the guarantees provided by `HashMap`, which allows you to modify `V` while assuming that `K` always stays constant: There is no way to get a `&mut K` for a `HashMap`, but you can get a `&mut V`; if `K` is actually a `&V`, one could easily modify `K` through `V` (by ways of mutating `Foo.a` ) and break the map.

One possibility is to change `Foo.a` from a `String` to a `Rc<str>`, which you can clone with minimal runtime cost in order to put the value both in the `K` and into `V`. As `Rc<str>` is `Borrow<str>`, you can still look up values in the map by means of `&str`. This still has the - theoretical - downside that you can break the map by getting a `&mut Foo` from the map and `std::mem::swap` the `a`, which makes it impossible to look up the correct value from its keys; but you'd have to do that deliberately.

Another option is to actually use a `HashSet` instead of a `HashMap`, and use a newtype for `Foo` which behaves like a `Foo.a`. You'd have to implement `PartialEq`, `Eq`, `Hash` (and `Borrow<str>` for good measure) like this:

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    a: String,
    b: String,
}

/// A newtype for `Foo` which behaves like a `str`
#[derive(Debug)]
struct FooEntry(Foo);

/// `FooEntry` compares to other `FooEntry` only via `.a`
impl PartialEq<FooEntry> for FooEntry {
    fn eq(&self, other: &FooEntry) -> bool {
        self.0.a == other.0.a
    }
}

impl Eq for FooEntry {}

/// It also hashes the same way as a `Foo.a`
impl std::hash::Hash for FooEntry {
    fn hash<H>(&self, hasher: &mut H)
    where
        H: std::hash::Hasher,
    {
        self.0.a.hash(hasher);
    }
}

/// Due to the above, we can implement `Borrow`, so now we can look up
/// a `FooEntry` in the Set using &str
impl std::borrow::Borrow<str> for FooEntry {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &str {
        &self.0.a
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo_1 = Foo {
        a: "foo".to_string(),
        b: "bar".to_string(),
    };

    let foo_2 = Foo {
        a: "foobar".to_string(),
        b: "barfoo".to_string(),
    };

    let foo_vec = vec![foo_1, foo_2];

    let mut foo_hashmap = HashSet::new();

    foo_vec.into_iter().for_each(|foo| {
        foo_hashmap.insert(FooEntry(foo));
    });

    // Look up `Foo` using &str as keys...
    println!("{:?}", foo_hashmap.get("foo").unwrap().0);
    println!("{:?}", foo_hashmap.get("foobar").unwrap().0);
}
```

Notice that `HashSet` provides no way to get a `&mut FooEntry` due to the reasons described above. You'd have to use `RefCell` (and read what the docs of `HashSet` have to say about this).

The third option is to simply `clone()` the `foo.a` as you described. Given the above, this is probably the most simple solution. If using an `Rc<str>` doesn't bother you for other reasons, this would be my choice.

*Sidenote*: If you don't need to modify `a` and/or `b`, a `Box<str>` instead of `String` is smaller by one machine word.

Comment: That's quite a neat trick with using HashSet and a newtype. Brilliant. I don't know any other standard libraries with this level of capability.