# How to implement a map on the top of a btree?

Tags: rust

Assumption: I know there is a BTreeMap in the std.

Lets say we have some Btree structure:

```
BTree<T: Ord + Eq>
```

And we want to implement a map using it:

```
struct Node<K: Ord + Eq, V> {
  k: K,
  v: MaybeUninit<V>
}

struct MyMap<K: Ord + Eq, V> {
  tree: BTree<Node<K, V>>
}

impl<K: Ord + Eq, V> MyMap<K, V> {
  fn put(&mut self, k: K, v: V) {
    self.tree.put(Node { k, v: MaybeUninit::new(v) })
  }

  fn contains(&self, k: &K) -> bool {
    let node = Node { k: ???, v: MaybeUninit::uninit() }
    self.tree.contains(&node)
    ...
  }
}
```

Because BTree::contains() expects a &T (in this case &Node<K, V>), but MyMap<K,V>::contains recieves a &K as a parameter so how to instantiate a Node<K, V> with &K?

**UPDATE (based on the comments)**

Lets get out an unknown external BTree and use just a std::BTreeSet.

```
struct Map<K, V> {
  inner: BTreeSet<MapEntry<K, V>>
}

struct MapEntry<K, V> {
  key: K,
  value: V
}

impl<K: Ord, V> MyMap<K, V> {

  fn push(&mut self, key: K, value: V) {
    self.inner.insert(MapEntry{ key, value })
  }

  fn contains(&self, key: impl Borrow<K>) {
    ???
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I have found that a construct like this:

```
pub fn get<Q>(&self, key: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Ord + ?Sized,
```

works beacause Q is "internally matched" to BTreeMap's K (as BTreeSet sits on the top of it). But If I have a dumb tree like the following:

```
struct MyTree<T: Ord> {
  root: Vec<T>
}
```

this would not work, because you cannot use type Q to compare keys  against Vec anyhow. So as to make this work the tree must be refactored to something like this:

```
struct MyTree<T: Borrow<K>, K: Ord> {
  root: Vec<T>,
  _pd: PhantomData<K>
}
```

Am I right that for **struct MyTree<T: Ord>** any wrappers in such case are impossible?

**UPDATE 3**
Rereading comments and thinking for a day I've finally managed to solve this! :

```
fn main() {    
    let mut map = Map::new();
    map.put(500, 600);

    println!("{} = 600", map.get(500).unwrap().1);
    println!("{} = 600", map.get(&500).unwrap().1);
}

struct BTree<T> {
    data: Vec<T>
}

impl<T: Ord> BTree<T> {

    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { data: vec!() }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, val: T) {
        self.data.push(val);
    }

    fn get<K>(&self, key: impl Borrow<K>) -> Option<&T>
    where
        T: Borrow<K>,
        K: Ord {
        self.data.iter().find(|&e| e.borrow() == key.borrow())
    }
}

struct Map<K, V> {
    tree: BTree<Node<K, V>>
}

impl<K: Ord, V> Map<K, V> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self { tree: BTree::new() }
    }

    fn put(&mut self, key: K, val: V) {
        self.tree.add(Node{ key, val  })
    }

    fn contains(&self, key: impl Borrow<K>) -> bool {
        self.get(key).is_some()
    }

    fn get(&self, key: impl Borrow<K>) -> Option<(&K, &V)> {
        self.tree.get(key).map(|Node{ key, val }| (key, val))        
    }
}

struct Node<K, V> {
    key: K,
    val: V
}

impl<K: Eq, V> Eq for Node<K, V> {}

impl<K: PartialEq, V> PartialEq for Node<K, V> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.key == other.key
    }
} 

impl<K: PartialOrd, V> PartialOrd for Node<K, V> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<std::cmp::Ordering> {
        self.key.partial_cmp(&other.key)
    }
}

impl<K: Ord, V> Ord for Node<K, V> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.key.cmp(&other.key)
    }

}

impl<K, V> Borrow<K> for Node<K, V> {
    fn borrow(&self) -> &K {
        &self.key
    }
}
```

Also I wanted a "clean access" for Copy types, like **map.get(500)** versus **map.get(&500)** for a **Map<i32, _>**. So changed **get** method to:

```
pub fn get<Q, K>(&self, key: K) -> Option<&V>
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Ord {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Does `Node` need to respect `V` at all while inside the `BTree`? That is, are all `Node<K, V>` for any `V` considered equal? If so, you can implement `Borrow` for `Node` (and it's semantic requirements, `Hash` and `Eq`) in terms of `K`, so a `Node<K, V>` behaves exactly like any `K`. You can then look-up any `Node<K, V>` using only `&K`.

Comment: @user2722968, can you provide an example if I cannot modify any code inside the BTree?

Comment: @user3030377, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72776613/struct-property-as-key-and-the-struct-itself-as-value-in-hashmaps/72778152#72778152 and the implementation of `FooEntry`. If implemented, the question remains why you need a `BTree<Node<K, V>>` (which behaves like a `BTree<K>`) instead of using a `BTreeMap<K, V>`, but you alluded to that in the comment above.

Comment: Can you please specify the signature of `BTree::contains()`? For example, [`BTreeSet::contains()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#method.contains) doesn't accept `&T`, it accepts `&Q` where `Q` is any type for which `T` implements `Borrow<Q>`. This allows one, for example, to look up a `&str` (rather than `&String`) in a `BTreeSet<String>`. If the `BTree` you're using has this feature too, and you control `Node`, then you can implement `Borrow<K>` for `Node<K>`, allowing `&K` to be passed to `BTreeSet::<Node<K, V>>::contains()`.

Comment: See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b8ca024d90655870962247da87d49951) for an example of how to implement `Borrow<K> for Node<K, V>` and use it in `contains()` impl. If `BTree::<T>::contains()` insists on receiving a `&T`, you're probably out of luck, and will need to either require `MyMap::contains()` to receive an owned `K` which you'll use to construct `Node`, or require `K: Clone` bound and clone it internally, which is just as bad (because it hides the cloning from the API user).

Comment: @user4815162342, Thank you for the link, it seems like what I need, will investigate it soon.

Comment: Why can't you use `Borrow` with `Vec`? You need to iterate over it anyway, so just `borrow()`.